# Integrating LATEX in my codeIgniter project

Tags: codeigniter, latex

I am exhausted  searching for the way to integrate LATEX in my codeigniter project. But i cant find any way. In my website I need to insert and show mathematical terms and figures in HTML.
how can i easily do i don't know.If LATEX is the only way what is the easy way to do that.

would you please suggest me a way.

Comment: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/44486/pixel-perfect-vertical-alignment-of-image-rendered-tex-snippets/45621#45621  But its Perl programme...

Comment: and this guy ported to PHP - http://filipivianna.blogspot.co.uk/2009/03/petry-rendered-latex-equations-using.html see if it helps

Comment: what I need exactly is to view them ( expressions ) as plain HTML not as image . Is it possible ?

Comment: oh.. tnx probably it will do !!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you save the latex code in the server-side and when you are showing on the website in HTML you can perform the conversion using [Pandoc](http://pandoc.org/) (a universal markup languages conversor).

But I'm not sure if this would work for mathematical symbols. Maybe you need to use another program (eg [ImageMagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)).